# 真心 VS 认真 difference

Tags: word-choice

I was trying to say “*He made this with all his heart*” and then looked for how to say “*with all one’s heart*” in Chinese. I found a lot of ways to express the sentence but I’m still not sure which one would be the most suitable because there were a lot of words and idioms that appeared:

> 真心，认真，诚心，全心全意，真心实意.

I’m not sure if native speakers often use those idioms, therefore I’m going to kick both idioms (全心全意 and 真心实意) out of the list, leaving the rest: 真心，认真，and 诚心.

However, 诚心 comes as a noun in the dictionary (even though it also comes as an adjective, but the first word class of 诚心 that appeared was noun and I didn’t see any sentence that used it as an adverb). Leaving only 真心 and 认真. I’m not sure the difference between both words though. Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: "真心"= truly heart, "認真"= serious/earnest, "誠心"=sincerely, "全心全意"=whole-heartedly, "真心實意"= similar to Sincerely.

Comment: The translation would be more accurate if you can clarify what is "this" in “He made this with all his heart”

Answer (score 3):

真心 is sincerity (usually in emotional / relationship kind of manner)， while 认真 is serious.

我是真心的  I am sincere (about it)

我是认真的  I am serious (about it)

Answer (score 2):

I would say ‘他很用心地做了这件事’, where ‘用心’ means ‘with all his heart’.

Comment: Wow, I just knew about 用心. Well, I also found someone said “用真心”. Seems like there’s still a lot more words to express “with all one’s heart” in Chinese ㅠㅠㅠㅠ thank you for the answer! I truly appreciate it. I’m still hoping to know how these words differ though 

Comment: You’re welcome! I think ‘认真’ is closer to ‘careful’. Others are similar though.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the options including those that were excluded at the first place can be used for "he made this with all his heart". It highly depends on the context. A lot of these words and idioms can be interchangeable, I have to say.

As there is an "all" in your sentence, using 全心全意 would be suitable, as “全” emphasises "all".

I assume the context is that the boy made a present for his girlfriend that he loves so much. So, 他全心全意地做了一件礼物。

Hope this can help.

Comment: Your question is interesting and makes me think twice of each option, so I 认真地 answered it. As a new contributor, I 诚心地 answered the question, because I 真心地 want to earn some reputation. ：）